# Handling a GET request in Node.js Express server: res.render(file.ejs, data) not working because data is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, ejs

In a server made with Express in Node.js, I have the following code for handling a GET request:

```
function articleReturner(celien) { // function querying a database (celien is a string, cetarticle is a JSON)
    Article.findOne({ lien: celien}, function (err, cetarticle){ 
                console.log(cetarticle); // it works
                return cetarticle;
    });
}

app.get('/selection/oui/', function(req, res) { // the URL requested ends with ?value=http://sweetrandoms.com, for example
    var celien = req.param("value"); // 
    console.log(celien); // it works
    articleReturner(celien); // calling the function defined above
    res.render('selection_form.ejs', cetarticle); // doesn't work!
    });
```

I know that data from the URL routing is correctly obtained by the server since the console correctly displays `celien` (a string). I also know that the `function articleReturner(celien)` is correctly querying the database because the console correctly displays `cetarticle` (a JSON).

But `res.render('selection_form.ejs', cetarticle);` is not working and the console displays `ReferenceError: cetarticle is not defined`... What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function articleReturner is executed asynchronously  and `return cetarticle;` doesn't make a lot of sense. You need to use callbacks or promises. Here is the code that uses callback to return result from articleReturner:

```
function articleReturner(celien, callback) { 
  Article.findOne({ lien: celien}, function (err, cetarticle){ 
            console.log(cetarticle); 
            callback(err,cetarticle);
 });
}

app.get('/selection/oui/', function(req, res) { 
  var celien = req.param("value"); // 
  console.log(celien); // it works
  articleReturner(celien, function(err, cetarticle){
    res.render('selection_form.ejs', cetarticle); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it, but it does not seem to work. The console displays the following message: `ReferenceError: C:\Users\Gabrielle\views\selection_form.ejs:1 >> 1| <%= cetarticle.titre %> cetarticle is not defined`...

Comment: It seems you have <%= cetarticle.titre %> in your selection_form.ejs file but don't provide cetarticle as input. Try to change res.render('selection_form.ejs', cetarticle); to res.render('selection_form.ejs',{cetarticle:cetarticle} );